# Action and ActionListener are not invoked for p:remoteCommand

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm using `p:remoteCommand`,its working fine for `update` and `process` except its not invoking either `action` method nor `actionListener`

**Xhtml Code**

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
   <h:outputLabel id="tempAge" value="#{remoteBean.tempAge}"/>

   <h:inputText id="age" value="#{remoteBean.age}" onkeypress="callRem()">
      <f:validateLongRange minimum="18"/>
   </h:inputText>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     var timex=0;
     function callRem(){
    clearTimeout(timex);
    timex = setTimeout("remote()",2000);
      }
   </script>

   <p:remoteCommand     name="remote" 
            process="age" 
            update="tempAge"
            action="#{remoteBean.act}" 
            actionListener="#{remoteBean.listen}">
   </p:remoteCommand>

</h:form>
```

**Managed Bean Code**

```
@ManagedBean
public class RemoteBean {
    private int age=18;
    private int tempAge=20;
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println("Setting age :"+age);
    }
    public int getTempAge() {
        return tempAge;
    }
    public void setTempAge(int tempAge) {
        this.tempAge = tempAge;
    }

    public void act(){
        System.out.println("in action()");
        tempAge+=age+2;
    }

     public void listen(ActionEvent event) {
         System.out.println("in Action Listener");
         tempAge+=age+2;
     }

}
```

I can't figure out where I'm doing wrong, may be its the Javascript code i've written.
If anyone faces and solved same issue please help.

*Using: Primefaces 3.5*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried yours example and found problem.
Seemse when you processing only age (process="age"), it executes only age input and ignores remoteCommand actionListener and action.
So you can change it to:

```
process="@form"
```

or

```
process="@this age"
```

worked both for me.

ps. I used View scope here.

Comment: Thanks Darka this solved my problem. I included @this in my list of elements to process.